# Great joy when finding insights in Torah: sayings of Rav Reuvain Grozovsky

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, jewish-books

[This](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/1892312/ten-thoughts-and-sayings-of-rav-reuvain-grozovsky-ztl.html) article shares some wonderful sayings of [Rav Reuvain Grozovsky zt"l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refael_Reuvain_Grozovsky#). One of these is:

> Torah is life itself. Since Torah is so precious and valuable, a person should be in a state of great joy for every insight in Torah that he creates – for every question he has, and for every answer.  As a result he will endeavor to sharpen it, clarify it, write it and spread it.  He should do this also for his friend’s insights too **(Maamarei Rav Reuvain p.22)**

> If one does not feel the simcha in the learning of Torah it is because he never truly tasted Torah in the correct and proper manner. **(Lev Ruevain p.416)**

I was looking for these two source for days, but unfortunately, could not find it on the internet.

Does anyone know if 1) **Maamarei Rav Reuvain p.22** and 2) **Lev Ruevain p. 416** can be found online? If so, could somebody share it?

Comment: See https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/61349/p/-1/t/827980/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c for ספר מאמרי רבי ראובן על התורה - I haven't seen any online access for לב ראובן

Comment: @EraserX TY! מאמרי רבי (כנ ) doesn't seems to have the particulair quote. I can't find it, maybe that's just my bad. Do you know where it can be found? Especially the part of "for every question he has, and for every answer. As a result he will endeavor to sharpen it, clarify it, write it and spread it. He should do this also for his friend’s insights too"?